# How do I push all my mercurial branches and tags using the hggit extension?

Tags: git, mercurial, hg-git

I am trying to convert my mercurial repository to git using the hggit extension.

As far as I can tell, it pushes everything over into one branch and one branch only.

How do I push over all my branches and tags using this extension?

Comment: Lazy Badger's answer has a link to the documentation that describes how you must configure `git.branch_bookmark_suffix` - for whatever reason, for me this link goes only to the top of the page, rather than directly to the `git.branch_bookmark_suffix` part. But, see that.

Comment: So can someone confirm the veracity of this statement: "In order to convert all you branches from hg to git, you must create a bookmark for each branch in mercurial"?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one big thing: Git "branches" and Mercurial branches are very different. And [additional trick](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/src/default/README.md#markdown-header-gitbranch_bookmark_suffix) at HG-side is **mandatory** for pushing *named branches* to Git-repo